# Android files gone and cant open files in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse

So, I have searched the solutions for my current problem but it seems it can’t solve with my situation. I use eclipse Juno that I downloaded from developer.android.com.

First, I imported my existing files from C:\Users\Name\workspace. I also ticked to copy project into workspace. But then following error appears: (see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/inmRg.jpg)

```
Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.
Project has no target set. Edit the project properties to set one.
Parser exception for /Astra/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file.
Parser exception for /Astra/AndroidManifest.xml: Premature end of file.
```

And, everytime I copied my existing file to android workspace, all of the data imported in my C:\User\Name\workspace[Imported Project] is gone.. All the files became empty (see: i.stack.imgur.com/jFYhm.jpg)

After that, I also realized all files that I want to open can not be viewed in Eclipse Juno. (from file>open file>browse>open) It only shows [X] button but without the file name or the content inside. (see proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6l6r.png).

add: 
I also tried another method based on this reply:
stackoverflow.com/questions/2231474/how-to-import-existing-android-project-into-eclipse?rq=1

and followed these steps:

```
File → Import → General → Existing Projects into Workspace → Next
Select root directory: /path/to/project
Projects → Select All
Uncheck Copy projects into workspace and Add project to working sets
Finish
```

But in the end, it only shows this pop up:

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please tell me what I should do. I can create new files and copy my data from notepad or else. But I prefer not to do that, because there is high chance that I need to import the project or refresh the project from my workspace. I want to know how to solve this issue.

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Create new Android project.

In Project Explorer in drop-down menu disable filter for .* files (Filters --> .* resource)

Now compare content of 3 files .project, .classpath, AndroidManifest.xml between new project and your project.